# Places Search Box - open suggestion by .click() + .click() on first result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I would appreciate your help on following problem.

I use google maps with a autosuggestion search box, such as i.e. [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=de)

I modify the value of this box with a

```
jquery('#myboxid').val('searchtext'),
```

in the given google example page (no jquery)

```
$('#pac-input').value = 'searchtext';
```

would work.

Now my goal is to trigger a click event inside '#myboxid' to display the google autosuggestion and again click on the first result.

Everything I read and tried so far like

```
jquery('#myboxid').click()
jquery('#myboxid').focus()
jquery('#myboxid').keydown()
```

did not work for me.

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards,

Felix

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pac-input')
```

is a simplest way to write

```
jQuery('#pac-input')
```

[More here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

So your problem must be anywhere else. Check if you're input is rendered BEFORE calling focus by using [ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```